# How to set the transactionnal option per test class in a spock integration test?

Tags: grails, groovy, integration-testing, spock

In a grails project (version 2.3.7) , i have an integration test using Spock :

```
class SimpleIntegrationTests extends IntegrationSpec{
   void "test an action from controller to database"(){...}
}
```

This integration test launch a batch with Spring Batch. Spring batch does not accept when a batch is launched from an existing transaction :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Existing transaction detected in JobRepository. Please fix this and try again
```

So i tell my integration test to run without transaction, with :

```
static transactional = false
```

Doing this, the test runs with success.

But there are other integration tests in my project, which need transactions to run correctly.
And the instruction "transactionnal = false" in my test class is not confined to this test class, but affects all other integration tests triggered after my test class.

I understood there is an alphabetically execution order for the tests. So i know that if i rename my test class to be the last test class to run, it works fine, and all my tests are successful. But i think it s not an ideal answer to the problem.

So my question is : how to define that a test class is non transactionnal, in a manner that does not affect other integration tests ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and I imagine you've found a solution already, but as a work around I think you need to explicitly specify `static transactional = true` on integration tests that you still want to be transactional. We've had a similar issue with our Grails 2.3.7 test suite...